# Unable to unpack django context data into template that renders heatmap

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a heatmap as part of a django template. I am sending the 2D data required for the heatmap from my view but I am having difficulties unpacking the context data.

In my view:

context['heatmap']=[[32, 22, 48, 77, 0, 6], [19, 12, 28, 30, 0, 3], [15, 30, 144, 70, 29, 31]]

In my template

var ZValues = [{% for value in heatmap %} "{{ value }}", {% endfor %}];

My attempt does not work. Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: how about `var ZValues = "{{heatmap}}"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can try like this:

```
// in template embedded script tag
<script>
var ZValues = JSON.parse("{{heatmap}}")
</script>
```

Comment: A Syntax Error. JSON.parse. Unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

Comment: can you console.log the heatmap like this `console.log("{{heatmap}}")`.

Comment: My apologies. Your solution worked. I had made an error with the syntax. Thank you!